# I want to alter the new custom fields to sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_item table

Tags: sales-order

I have created one custom module, now I need to alter some fields into the table sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_item , I have used following alter queries:

```
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_item` ADD COLUMN `sweet_tooth_label` VARCHAR( 60 ) 
ALTER TABLE sales_flat_order ADD COLUMN `sweet_tooth_label` VARCHAR( 60 )
```

but it won't work for me.
Please suggest me any best solution.

Comment: have you any table prefix

Comment: No I want to add custom fields to core tables i.e. sales_flat_order

Comment: check table is in innodb or myasm

Comment: SQL syntax is correct but try `ALTER TABLE `test` ADD `sweet_tooth_label` VARCHAR(60)` as well. Include the error message in your post. Run the query directly, and it will give you an error, if it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, error message would be great. Also - if it's a custom module, please use an installer. It is extremely bad practise to use direct SQL statements in magento imho